# "Unable to install Wine as download failed" in Ubuntu Software

Tags: 18.04, wine, software-center

When I try to install wine from Ubuntu software the following message comes up:

[image: download failed, 404]

> Unable to install Wine as download failed: `E: http://in.archive.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsane1 amd64 1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2.1 is not (yet) available (404 Not Found [IP: 103.123.234.254 80])`

Comment: Run `sudo apt update`, wait for it to complete, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the version in the Ubuntu Software Center is not suitable for your device or something else so I'm telling an alternative way you can install WINE on your system. Run the following commands:

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. `wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`
3. `sudo apt-key add winehq.key`
4. **For 18.04** `sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'`

   **For 19.04** `sudo apt-add-repository 'deb
   https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'`

   **For 19.10** `sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main'`
5. `sudo apt update`
6. `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Comment if you are facing any issues.

Comment: ran the codes for 18.04. didn't work

Comment: I ran the codes again. Now it worked. Thank you

Comment: Happy to hear it worked. If you got the satisfactory answer then an upvote will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming back to this after a long while, so I'm coming across a lot of these kinds of problems and you guys are amazing.

I was having this same problem, and the solution that worked for me was on the WineHQ wiki of all things:

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

I'm going to break each step up into its own comment.

**Preparation**

If your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):

`$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

**Add the repository.**

Download and add the repository key:

`$ sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings`

`$ sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`

**Select your Ubuntu version and download the WineHQ sources file:
Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)**

`$ sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/lunar/…`

**Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)**

`$ sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/…`

**Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) Linux Mint 21.x**

`$ sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/…`

**Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) Linux Mint 20.x**

`$ sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/…`

**Update the package information:**

`$ sudo apt update Install Wine Stable branch`

`$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable Development branch`

`$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel Staging branch`

`$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging`

In the same spirit, I'm going to post the possible problems he also has:

Third-party repositories WineHQ packages are created and tested for a clean Ubuntu installation. Using PPAs or third-party repositories may prevent the installation of Wine. Often the problem is that these repositories are not multiarch. The required 32 and 64-bit packages are missing or cannot be installed side by side. The deb.sury.org repository is known for causing problems. Downgrade the problematic dependency packages to the official Ubuntu version.

KDE Neon - Ubuntu 22.04 KDE Neon users report problems with the libpoppler-glib8 dependency. The solution is to downgrade this package to the official Ubuntu version.

`$ sudo apt install libpoppler-glib8:{i386,amd64}=22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1`

Backports - Another cause may be the use of backports. A newer 64-bit version of a library is already installed, but the 32-bit version isn't. These packages are given a lower priority so they will not be installed automatically. The solution is to manually install the missing 32-bit package from backports.

FAudio- Older versions of Wine (prior to version 6.21) have FAudio as a dependency. These packages are missing on Ubuntu 18.04. These can be downloaded from the Open Build Service. For Debian 10, these packages are available in backports.

Winehq key problems W: GPG error: dl.winehq.org ... NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F Currently, the Wine servers are being synchronized. This means that some users still getting the older .sources file. If you get this warning, edit the winehq-.sources file and replace /usr/share/keyrings/ to /etc/apt/keyrings/. For example:

`$ sudo sed -i s@/usr/share/keyrings/@/etc/apt/keyrings/@ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources`

The WineHQ repository key was changed on 2018-12-19 If you downloaded and added the key before that time, you will need to download and add the new key and run sudo apt update to accept the repository changes. Apt-key is now deprecated Previously, apt-key was used to add the Wine key. If you get this warning, remove the Wine key with:

`$ sudo apt-key del "D43F 6401 4536 9C51 D786 DDEA 76F1 A20F F987 672F"`

And remove the the line about the WineHQ repository from /etc/apt/sources.list(.d/*).

Mirror sync in progress? If you get an error message when trying to install a package from WineHQ that includes the line Mirror sync in progress? that is most likely the problem. There are many packages to sync, and it can take a long time to complete. Wait a few hours, and try again. If the problem persists for more than a day, file a bug.

I just followed the instructions and I've got Wine now.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for posting it … if you can put the steps in (rather than just the link) it’s much better - just in case the link breaks which would make your answer useless. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - if you edit your answer with that information you can format as you want!

Comment: I'm going to break each step up into its own comment.

Preparation

If your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

Comment: Add the repository. Download and add the repository key:
$ sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
$ sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key

Comment: Select your Ubuntu version and download the WineHQ sources file:
Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
$ sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/lunar/winehq-lunar.sources

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)
$ sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/winehq-kinetic.sources

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) Linux Mint 21.x
$ sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) Linux Mint 20.x
$ sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/winehq-focal.sources

Comment: Update the package information:
$ sudo apt update

Install Wine
Stable branch 
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Development branch 
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel

Staging branch 
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging

Comment: In the same spirit, I'm going to post the possible problems he also has: Third-party repositories

WineHQ packages are created and tested for a clean Ubuntu installation. Using PPAs or third-party repositories may prevent the installation of Wine. Often the problem is that these repositories are not multiarch. The required 32 and 64-bit packages are missing or cannot be installed side by side. The deb.sury.org repository is known for causing problems.

Downgrade the problematic dependency packages to the official Ubuntu version.

Comment: KDE Neon - Ubuntu 22.04 KDE Neon users report problems with the libpoppler-glib8 dependency. The solution is to downgrade this package to the official Ubuntu version. $ sudo apt install libpoppler-glib8:{i386,amd64}=22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1

Comment: Backports - Another cause may be the use of backports. A newer 64-bit version of a library is already installed, but the 32-bit version isn't. These packages are given a lower priority so they will not be installed automatically. The solution is to manually install the missing 32-bit package from backports.

Comment: FAudio- Older versions of Wine (prior to version 6.21) have FAudio as a dependency. These packages are missing on Ubuntu 18.04. These can be downloaded from the Open Build Service. For Debian 10, these packages are available in backports.

Comment: Winehq key problems

    W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/ ... NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F

Currently, the Wine servers are being synchronized. This means that some users still getting the older .sources file. If you get this warning, edit the winehq-<distro>.sources file and replace /usr/share/keyrings/ to /etc/apt/keyrings/.

For example:$  sudo sed -i s@/usr/share/keyrings/@/etc/apt/keyrings/@ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources

Comment: The WineHQ repository key was changed on 2018-12-19

If you downloaded and added the key before that time, you will need to download and add the new key and run sudo apt update to accept the repository changes.

    Apt-key is now deprecated

Previously, apt-key was used to add the Wine key. If you get this warning, remove the Wine key with: $ sudo apt-key del "D43F 6401 4536 9C51 D786 DDEA 76F1 A20F F987 672F" And remove the the line about the WineHQ repository from /etc/apt/sources.list(.d/*).

Comment: Mirror sync in progress?

If you get an error message when trying to install a package from WineHQ that includes the line Mirror sync in progress? that is most likely the problem. There are many packages to sync, and it can take a long time to complete.

Wait a few hours, and try again. If the problem persists for more than a day, file a bug.

Comment: I hope that all helps. Thank you again.